# filtering and array of objects by an array of string in the object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects, on the objects there is a key of gender with an array of strings. The gender array is empty `[]` or has one string with either `["men"]` or `["women"]`. I'm trying sort the array of objects into an array depending on what gender is active. I.e if the gender `men` is active, all the objects with `gender: ["men"]` should be filtered into the array. Most importantly, any objects that have an empty array, like `gender: []` should also be included in both the men and women arrays. However, i'm having trouble getting this to work, my code is currently returning an array of undefineds. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
const activeGender = "women"

const images = [
    {
      "gender": [],
      "image": {
        "_id": "ac0611e600fd31bb3dc87f4b514d0b80erf8fa3b5d-f2759x4139-jpg",
        "url": "https://cdn.example.com/images/zjeoztkz/production/ac0611e600fd31bb3dc87f4b514dfr0b80f8fa3b5d-2759x4139.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "gender": ["women"],
      "image": {
        "_id": "ac0611e600fd31bb3dc87f4b514d0b80f8fa3b5d-2759x4139-jpg",
        "url": "https://cdn.example.com/images/zjeoztkz/production/ac0611e600fd31bb3dc87f4b514d0b80f8fa3b5d-2759x4139.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "gender": ["men"],
      "image": {
        "_id": "4b733a931e13d7cdf77c200d0eac94b55caee89e-3766x5649-jpg",
        "url": "https://cdn.example.com/images/zjeoztkz/production/4b733a931e13d7cdf77c200d0eac94b55caee89e-3766x5649.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "gender": ["men"],
      "image": {
        "_id": "f2a4ce65ce4f671c6aec4d9b6b8b2bce7b4a1e7a-5472x3648-jpg",
        "url": "https://cdn.example.com/images/zjeoztkz/production/f2a4ce65ce4f671c6aec4d9b6b8b2bce7b4a1e7a-5472x3648.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "gender": ["women"],
      "image": {
        "_id": "31ab7886b5b2164e245ffb41facc01c0ac66f60f-1962x2942-jpg",
        "url": "https://cdn.example.com/images/zjeoztkz/production/31ab7886b5b2164e245ffb41facc01c0ac66f60f-1962x2942.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "gender": ["women"],
      "image": {
        "_id": "c577801db926fd058142513dce0b834eb8dc9e16-2432x3648-jpg",
        "url": "https://cdn.example.com/images/zjeoztkz/production/c577801db926fd058142513dce0b834eb8dc9e16-2432x3648.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "gender": ["women"],
      "image": {
        "_id": "e6e16e0da123fa510efe2ccb1269f18afa8cda64-5472x3648-jpg",
        "url": "https://cdn.example.com/images/zjeoztkz/production/e6e16e0da123fa510efe2ccb1269f18afa8cda64-5472x3648.jpg"
      }
    }
  ]
  

const getMens = (items) =>
  items
    .filter((i) => i.gender.length === 0 || i.gender.includes("men"))
    .map((i) => i.images)
    .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);
    
const getWomens = (items) =>
  items
    .filter((i) => i.gender.length === 0 || i.gender.includes("women"))
    .map((i) => i.images)
    .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);
    
  const filteredImages =
    activeGender === "women"
      ? getWomens(images)
      : getMens(images);
      
      console.log(filteredImages)
```

Comment: no need to edit.. we see it

Comment: i suspect it is because of reduce call, try removing it and inspecting output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a small typo in your code. `.map((i) => i.images)` should be `.map((i) => i.image)`.

```js
const activeGender = "women"

const images = [
    {
      "gender": [],
      "image": {
        "_id": "ac0611e600fd31bb3dc87f4b514d0b80erf8fa3b5d-f2759x4139-jpg",
        "url": "https://cdn.example.com/images/zjeoztkz/production/ac0611e600fd31bb3dc87f4b514dfr0b80f8fa3b5d-2759x4139.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "gender": ["women"],
      "image": {
        "_id": "ac0611e600fd31bb3dc87f4b514d0b80f8fa3b5d-2759x4139-jpg",
        "url": "https://cdn.example.com/images/zjeoztkz/production/ac0611e600fd31bb3dc87f4b514d0b80f8fa3b5d-2759x4139.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "gender": ["men"],
      "image": {
        "_id": "4b733a931e13d7cdf77c200d0eac94b55caee89e-3766x5649-jpg",
        "url": "https://cdn.example.com/images/zjeoztkz/production/4b733a931e13d7cdf77c200d0eac94b55caee89e-3766x5649.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "gender": ["men"],
      "image": {
        "_id": "f2a4ce65ce4f671c6aec4d9b6b8b2bce7b4a1e7a-5472x3648-jpg",
        "url": "https://cdn.example.com/images/zjeoztkz/production/f2a4ce65ce4f671c6aec4d9b6b8b2bce7b4a1e7a-5472x3648.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "gender": ["women"],
      "image": {
        "_id": "31ab7886b5b2164e245ffb41facc01c0ac66f60f-1962x2942-jpg",
        "url": "https://cdn.example.com/images/zjeoztkz/production/31ab7886b5b2164e245ffb41facc01c0ac66f60f-1962x2942.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "gender": ["women"],
      "image": {
        "_id": "c577801db926fd058142513dce0b834eb8dc9e16-2432x3648-jpg",
        "url": "https://cdn.example.com/images/zjeoztkz/production/c577801db926fd058142513dce0b834eb8dc9e16-2432x3648.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "gender": ["women"],
      "image": {
        "_id": "e6e16e0da123fa510efe2ccb1269f18afa8cda64-5472x3648-jpg",
        "url": "https://cdn.example.com/images/zjeoztkz/production/e6e16e0da123fa510efe2ccb1269f18afa8cda64-5472x3648.jpg"
      }
    }
  ]
  

const getMens = (items) =>
  items
    .filter((i) => i.gender.length === 0 || i.gender.includes("men"))
    .map((i) => i.image)
    .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);
    
const getWomens = (items) =>
  items
    .filter((i) => i.gender.length === 0 || i.gender.includes("women"))
    .map((i) => i.image)
    .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);
    
  const filteredImages =
    activeGender === "women"
      ? getWomens(images)
      : getMens(images);
      
      console.log(filteredImages)
```

Answer (score 1):

"images" is undefined - it does not exist in your object you want

map((i) => i.image) instead....

```
const activeGender = "women"

const images = [
    {
      "gender": [],
      "image": {
        "_id": "ac0611e600fd31bb3dc87f4b514d0b80erf8fa3b5d-f2759x4139-jpg",
        "url": "https://cdn.example.com/images/zjeoztkz/production/ac0611e600fd31bb3dc87f4b514dfr0b80f8fa3b5d-2759x4139.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "gender": ["women"],
      "image": {
        "_id": "ac0611e600fd31bb3dc87f4b514d0b80f8fa3b5d-2759x4139-jpg",
        "url": "https://cdn.example.com/images/zjeoztkz/production/ac0611e600fd31bb3dc87f4b514d0b80f8fa3b5d-2759x4139.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "gender": ["men"],
      "image": {
        "_id": "4b733a931e13d7cdf77c200d0eac94b55caee89e-3766x5649-jpg",
        "url": "https://cdn.example.com/images/zjeoztkz/production/4b733a931e13d7cdf77c200d0eac94b55caee89e-3766x5649.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "gender": ["men"],
      "image": {
        "_id": "f2a4ce65ce4f671c6aec4d9b6b8b2bce7b4a1e7a-5472x3648-jpg",
        "url": "https://cdn.example.com/images/zjeoztkz/production/f2a4ce65ce4f671c6aec4d9b6b8b2bce7b4a1e7a-5472x3648.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "gender": ["women"],
      "image": {
        "_id": "31ab7886b5b2164e245ffb41facc01c0ac66f60f-1962x2942-jpg",
        "url": "https://cdn.example.com/images/zjeoztkz/production/31ab7886b5b2164e245ffb41facc01c0ac66f60f-1962x2942.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "gender": ["women"],
      "image": {
        "_id": "c577801db926fd058142513dce0b834eb8dc9e16-2432x3648-jpg",
        "url": "https://cdn.example.com/images/zjeoztkz/production/c577801db926fd058142513dce0b834eb8dc9e16-2432x3648.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "gender": ["women"],
      "image": {
        "_id": "e6e16e0da123fa510efe2ccb1269f18afa8cda64-5472x3648-jpg",
        "url": "https://cdn.example.com/images/zjeoztkz/production/e6e16e0da123fa510efe2ccb1269f18afa8cda64-5472x3648.jpg"
      }
    }
  ]
  

const getMens = (items) =>
  items
    .filter((i) => i.gender.length === 0 || i.gender.includes("men"))
    .map((i) => i.image)
    
    
const getWomens = (items) =>
  items
    .filter((i) => i.gender.length === 0 || (i.gender.includes("women")) )
    .map((i) => i.image)
    
    
  const filteredImages =
    activeGender === "women"
      ? getWomens(images)
      : getMens(images);
      
      console.log(filteredImages)
```